# CentOS release 5.10 - Whitelist source IP addresses

Tags: linux, centos

I want to set up CentOS 5.10 firewall such that, all the incoming requests will be blocked except from the originating IP addresses that I whitelist. How do I view what has been whitelisted, then add IPs to whitelist?

Comment: Look up `iptables` tutorials. Also, CentOS 5 is _ancient_ so likely will have various security holes, such as HeartBleed. I highly recommend a newer version of [Rocky](https://rockylinux.org/) (the spiritual successor to CentOS) or similar.

Comment: Whitelisting a single IP could break DNS resolution and make it impossible to send requests to non-whitelisted IPs. You really need to study networking and iptables to go along with this.